# How to disable HAProxy?

Tags: linux, haproxy

I have set up an F5 load balancer and wish to disable HAProxy.  I read through [the haproxy docs](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.7/doc/management.txt), but didn't find anything on how to outright disable the service.  I already disabled firewalld and keepalived (using `systemctl disable [service name]`).

When I run `haproxy -vv` I get:

```
HA-Proxy version 1.5.18 2016/05/10
Copyright 2000-2016 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>

Build options :
  TARGET  = linux2628
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DTCP_USER_TIMEOUT=18
  OPTIONS = USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_GETADDRINFO=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_REGPARM=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_PCRE=1

Default settings :
  maxconn = 2000, bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 8192, maxpollevents = 200

Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with zlib version : 1.2.7
Compression algorithms supported : identity, deflate, gzip
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports prefer-server-ciphers : yes
Built with PCRE version : 8.32 2012-11-30
PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.
```

Any pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: `systemctl disable haproxy` should prevent it from starting on the next boot. `systemctl disable --now haproxy` should disable it and stop it right then. Are you not finding a `haproxy` service?

Comment: @JohnMoon I added your answer as 'the' answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John Moon said in the comment above,

`systemctl disable haproxy` should prevent it from starting on the next boot. `systemctl disable --now haproxy` should disable it and stop it right then.